# git: how to "consolidate" the local commits

Tags: git, version-control, git-push, git-commit

I like to commit quite frequently (and even randomly) when I am working on some code, because if I screw up somewhere I can always roll back my changes.

However, when I decide to push all the changes to the master repository, I don't like people to see all the random commits, because some of them are really meaningless to them, and it makes the change tree unnecessarily long.

How do I "consolidate" all my local commits before I push?

Comment: The proper term is "squashing" commits. That should help you find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are doing, but it sounds like you may be developing on `master` (or whatever the main branch is for you).  If this is what is happening, then you probably should use branching in preference to the rebasing approaches described below. See Scott Chacon's book here: http://progit.org/book/ch3-4.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine your commits by rebase and squashing the ones you dont need.

Refere this: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

Comment: We generally delete link-only answers.  Could you [edit] and add some details?

Comment: That looks like a no, @user1228

Answer (score 2):

Do an [interactive rebase](http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/4_interactive_rebasing.html), which will let you reorder, squash and edit commits to your heart's content before pushing.

Answer (score 2):

`git rebase -i`

An interactive editor will be prompted out.

Change all commit you want to consolidate to "squash"

Quit the editor

Comment: Note that you must also specify the commit ID of the last commit _before_ the ones you want to squash: `git rebase -i <after-this-commit>`